# Tiling window manager that works relatively out of the box

Tags: i3, software-rec, tiling-wm

I was trying i3. I really enjoy controlling my PC, without moving hands from the keyboard, but there are a lot of basic functions that i3 doesn't support out of the box like sound or brightness control. It seems that there are also problems when you want to use multiple displays, etc. (I'm not sure about the displays, I've came across posts, talking about it while I was searching how to resolve my problems with sound control, but often I need to display plantations with my laptop so I'll need it).

While I think it's good for self-esteem to pizza yourself off writing scripts in order to change the brightness, I don't find it reasonable or productive. I've already lost a lot of time, and almost failed my PhD because of doing stuff like this instead of doing my homework.

Is there a tiling window manager that works out of the box? Or are there some packages for i3 or other tiling managers that will handle this basic stuff?

Comment: I'm wondering what changing screen brightness has to do with a window manager.

Comment: I use i3 with up to three monitors without problems. Screen brightness/sound control is not really your window manager's job.

Comment: No window-manager dose screen-brightness, or sound-volume-control. They will be a separate app.

Comment: Out of interest, how does one pizza one-self? Or any one else?

Comment: Multi-monitor is a window-manager thing though. Not all WMs support mulit-monitor.

Comment: @MarcWilson when i swich from kde to i3 I can't control the brightness so I guess that waht it hase to do, is that it deprive me of the ability to change the brigthness without bothering.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity ok thank you. Now I'll know that I can use it with multiple monitors.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor well I dindt knew the difference between WM and DE, but now I know thanks to the answare of bu5hman. But still if you know some separate app that can help i'll take it. 
And for the pizza, i wrote that to avoide using obscene language, but if i think deeply about it, i guess it'll be something like Cruella De Vil that get's caked here self (actually i don't really like the film, I just remember that scene)

Comment: Yes a desktop environment is not a thing. It is an environment, so a collection of things.

Answer (score 0):

The *basic* stuff you are looking for is *basic* to a DE, but not to a WM, so if you want all of that *out of the box* then stick to a DE.

That said you can roll just about any command you like and bind it to any key you want. I have been using i3 for about 2 weeks now and had to deal with the specific issue re brightness. The solution was a web search away over [here](https://sourabhtk37.github.io/blog/post/brightness-and-volume-control-i3/).

So my `.config` binds keys to a script....

```
# backlight control
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec sh ~/.config/i3/backlight.sh -inc 20
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec sh ~/.config/i3/backlight.sh -dec 20
```

And the script does the heavy lifting

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e 
file="/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness"

current=$(cat "$file")
new="$current"

if [ "$1" = "-inc" ]
then
    new=$(( current + $2 ))
fi

if [ "$1" = "-dec" ]
then
new=$(( current - $2 ))
fi

echo "$new" | tee "$file"
```

Time taken for web-search, mods and the script wasn't half an hour.

Though my productivity did take a while to recover after changing to colemak ...... a temporarily painful move but ultimately a worthwhile one (especially watching other people trying to type).

Comment: Thank you for your answere. I actually didn't know the difference between WM and DE. Now I've found this video that shows how to get tiling window managers for KDE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4pppzPxD3Q
I'll still try to fully configure my i3 because I like when it's minimalistic etc. without useless stuff but for the moment i guess it'll do what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to make i3 work with KDE plasma, xfce, and lxde.

The configuration with KDE is the less bugy in my case and the only one where the cation keys (volium and brightness control) works properly.

For KDE: There is a guide in this link https://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/Using_Other_Window_Managers_with_Plasma

And here is an other one: https://medium.com/@vishnu_mad/using-i3-window-manager-with-kde-plasma-c2ac70594d8

Personally i've used the methon on the second link and i've added some of the commands that I've took on the firs link, to my i3 config file.

In the end i've added the fallowing to my config file:

```
#____ Plasma Integration BEGIN _____

#Try to kill the wallpaper set by Plasma (it takes up the entire workspace
#and hides everythiing)
exec --no-startup-id wmctrl -c Plasma
for_window [title="Desktop — Plasma"] kill; floating enable; border none

#Avoid tiling popups, dropdown windows from plasma
for_window [class="plasmashell"] floating enable
for_window [class="Plasma"] floating enable
for_window [class="krunner"] floating enable
for_window [class="Kmix"] floating enable
#for_window [class="Klipper"] floating enable
#for_window [class="Plasmoidviewer"] floating enable

#____ Window Rules ____

#____ Avoid tiling for non-Plasma stuff ____
for_window [window_role="pop-up"] floating enable
for_window [window_role="bubble"] floating enable
for_window [window_role="task_dialog"] floating enable
for_window [window_role="Preferences"] floating enable
for_window [window_role="About"] floating enable
for_window [window_type="dialog"] floating enable
for_window [window_type="menu"] floating enable

#____ lol idk what programs this thig take care of ____

for_window [class="plasmashell"] floating enable;
for_window [class="Plasma"] floating enable; border none
for_window [title="plasma-desktop"] floating enable; border none
for_window [title="win7"] floating enable; border none
for_window [class="krunner"] floating enable; border none
for_window [class="Kmix"] floating enable; border none
for_window [class="Klipper"] floating enable; border none
for_window [class="Plasmoidviewer"] floating enable; border none
for_window [class="(?i)*nextcloud*"] floating disable
for_window [class="plasmashell" window_type="notification"] floating enable, border none, move right 700px, move down 450px
no_focus [class="plasmashell" window_type="notification"]

#____ Plasma Integration END _____
```

I found this article that shows how to combine xfce with i3 :

http://feeblenerd.blogspot.com/2015/11/pretty-i3-with-xfce.html

But in my case the brightness key doesn't work even with xfce lol (i mean, even the normal xfce, not the one opened with i3)

Also I've found this video that shows how to transform KDE default window manager in to a "quasi" tiling window manager :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4pppzPxD3Q

I've also found that you can combine i3 with LXDE by replacing the line `window_manager=openbox-lxde` by `window_manager=openbox-lxde` in `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf` and you also need to remove the line `@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE` in `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` but again there's a problem with the birghtness and sound controle